# Subresource uri with custom identifier

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I've got an entity with a [Custom Identifier](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/identifiers/) and a [Subresource](https://api-platform.com/docs/core/subresources/).

While the Organisation entity works fine (`/api/organisation/ABC`), so expected to have an endpoint like `/api/organisation/ABC/users`.

But no. The uri of the subresources is `/api/organisation/1/users`. This is the output:

```
{
  "@context": "/api/contexts/Organisation",
  "@id": "/api/organisations/1/users", <-- $id used as identifier
  "@type": "hydra:Collection",
  "hydra:member": [
    {
      "@id": "/api/users/1",
      "@type": "User",
      "organisation": {
        "@id": "/api/organisations/ABC",  <-- $code used as identifier
        "@type": "Organisation",
        "id": 701,
        "code": "VB",
        "createdAt": "2019-11-08T08:38:18+01:00",
        "updatedAt": "2019-11-08T08:38:52+01:00"
      },
    }
  ]
}
```

I'm using `api-platform/api-pack v1.2.2` and `api-platform/core v2.5.5`. This behaviour [isn't documented](https://github.com/api-platform/docs/issues/1115).

```
use ApiPlatform\Core\Annotation as Api;

class Organisation
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     *
     * @Api\ApiProperty(identifier=false)
     */
    protected ?int $id = null;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="text", nullable=true)
     *
     * @Api\ApiProperty(identifier=true, description="Code")
     */
    protected ?string $code = null;

    /**
     * @var Collection|User[]
     *
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="organisation")
     *
     * @Api\ApiSubresource(maxDepth=1)
     */
    protected $users;
}
```

Why does my custom identifier not work on subresources?

Comment: Code is nullable, identifiers shouldn't be nullable or set explicitly in order to work. I'd still like to check because it usually works when we do not have ID column as primary key at all.

Comment: Tested and updated issues, there are two of them stating same thing and yes indeed it's a bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While it seemed unlikely to me, it turns out to be a bug:

- https://github.com/api-platform/core/issues/3585
- https://github.com/api-platform/api-platform/issues/1542